# Getting length in a Form

Tags: angular, forms, ionic-framework

I have a Form that looks like this:

[image]

and i would like to get in TS the length of the "quantity" array and put it in a constant

I tried this :

```
getLength() {

const lengthValue = this.itemsForm.controls('items').controls('quantity').length();

return lenghtValue;
}
```

but it doesn't work at all

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
getLength() {

  var arrayControl = this.itemsForm.get('quantity') as FormArray;

  const lengthValue = arrayControl.length();

  return lenghtValue;
}
```

Comment: on the line : ``` const lengthValue = arrayControl.length(); ```    I get this error message : error TS2349: Cannot invoke an expression whose type lacks a call signature. Type 'Number' has no compatible call signatures.
[ng]

Answer (score 0):

It looks like length is a value not a function so try removing () from the end

```
getLength() {

const lengthValue = this.itemsForm.controls('items').controls('quantity').length;

return lenghtValue;
}
```

Comment: it doesn't work. I get this error message:     Cannot invoke an expression whose type lacks a call signature. Type '{ [key: string]: AbstractControl; }' has no compatible call signatures.ts(2349)

Answer (score 0):

Your 'items' control is a FormArray, not a FormGroup.

That means you access its controls by index, not by name.

The 'quantity' FormArray is a control of the FormGroup which is at index 0 of your 'items' formArray. Try the following:

```
const lengthValue = this.itemsForm.controls('items').controls[0].controls('quantity').length;
```

Comment: with your solution a get this error message:     Cannot invoke an expression whose type lacks a call signature. Type '{ [key: string]: AbstractControl; }' has no compatible call signatures.ts(2349)

Comment: Oops! I believe the issue is the `length()` part. Length is not a function. I've edited the code– it should simply be `...controls('quantity').length`

Comment: I gave the answer below :)

Answer (score 0):

@Adrita Sharma, @user8351493, @Michael Beeson

Hello Thanks for your help, it helps me to find the answer.

There is the correct syntax:

```
const lengthValue = ((this.itemsForm.get('items') as FormArray).at(0).get('quantity') as FormArray).length;
```

Answer (score 0):

`form.controls[name].value.toString().length`